# Javascript: Error in custom script for lazyload images

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to write the following script to lazyload background images of sub-menu on a website. But this function returns the error

> Missing ) after argument list

My requirement is to load the background images after the window loaded completely. What i am doing is , I have added some data attributes to get the background image url, position etc. and then on windows load call this function which adds the css for the sub-menu.

```
<script>
function menuImageLazyLoad() {
    var imgDefer = document.getElementsByClassName('megamenu-content');
    for (var i = 0; i < imgDefer.length; i++) {
        if(imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-background-image')) {
             imgDefer[i].css(
                "background-image":+imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-background-image'),
                "background-position":+imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-background-position'),
                "background-repeat":+imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-background-repeat')
             );
            console.log(imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-background-image'));
        }
    }
}
window.onload = menuImageLazyLoad;
</script>
```

console logs returns the url of image:

```
url(image/sub_menu_image.jpg)
```

How can i fix this problem?

**Update:**

**This is the final solution for my problem. I hope it may help someone**

```
<script>
function menuImageLazyLoad() {
    var imgDefer = document.getElementsByClassName('megamenu-content');
    for (var i = 0; i < imgDefer.length; i++) {
        if(imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-background-image')) {
           $(imgDefer[i]).css("background-image",imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-background-image'));
           $(imgDefer[i]).css("background-position",imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-background-position'));
           $(imgDefer[i]).css("background-repeat",imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-background-repeat'));
        }
    }
}
window.onload = menuImageLazyLoad;
</script>
```

Comment: .css() is method of jquery so this is wrong: imgDefer[i].css(). The correct use is: $(imgDefer[i]).css(); This solved the problem for me. For reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37537113/css-is-not-a-function-jquery/37537141

Answer (score 0):

I guess you miss `{}`
For multiple attribute css settings,
It should be set as an object https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css.asp

```
imgDefer[i].css(
            {"background-image":+imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-background-image'),
            "background-position":+imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-background-position'),
            "background-repeat":+imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-background-repeat')
         });
```

Comment: it returns: TypeError: imgDefer[i].css is not a function

Comment: did you put the {} correctly as my code, I pasted the code and run without error

Comment: .css() is method of jquery so this is wrong: imgDefer[i].css(). The correct use is: $(imgDefer[i]).css(); This solved the problem for me.